# Использование в коде переменных не известные компилятору до компиляции кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Я новичок в python
я столкнулся с тем что мне нужно сделать поле 8x8 квадратов в Tkinter, но делать его в ручную это долго, я почитал документацию и увидел функции exec() и eval().

суть вопроса вот в чём:

```py
    from tkinter import *
    class Main():
        def do_squares(self, number):
            for sqr_num in range(0, number):
                exec('self.square_' + str(sqr_num) + '=First()')
        def do_smthing_with_sqr(self, name):
            exec('self.' + name + '.value_1=False')

    class First():
        def __init__(self):
            self.value_1 = 'Something'
            self.value_2 = True
            self.Value_3 = 0

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Instance = Main()
        Instance.do_squares(64)
        print(Instance.square_62.value_1)
        Instance.do_smthing_with_sqr('square_62')
        print(Instance.square_62.value_1)
```

всё работает верно но вопрос в том, приветствуется ли данный подход,

```
print(Instance.square_62.value_1)
```

ведь в данной строке кода мы лишь подсознательно понимаем что переменная "square_62" будет создана но на данный момент её нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, использование exec и eval рекомендуется всячески избегать. И если вам кажется что у вас возникла потребность использовать их в прикладном коде, то, скорее всего, вы что-то делает не так.

А для вашей цели нужно использовать такие инструменты языка, как коллекции - например, словари и списки.

Например, вы можете создать один список value и заполнить его всеми нужными значениями:

```
value = ['Something', True, 0]
```

Теперь вы можете обратится к любому элементу по его номеру (только следует помнить, что нумерация в программировании начинается с нуля):

```
print(value[1])  # Напечатает 'True'
```

Коллекции очень удобно использовать в цикле:

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    print(value[i])

# Напечатает:
# 'Something'
# True
# 0
```

или даже проще:

```
for element in value:
    print(element)
```